# SQL Server / TSQL cast smalldatetime using isnull

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, casting

I'm trying to just do a simple check against a column in the table:

```
If (endDate is null)
    use smalldatetime '12/31/2200'
else
    use endDate from column
```

Here is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getCostByDate] @date smalldatetime, @productID int
AS
SELECT cost 
FROM testDB.dbo.product_cost
WHERE @date between startDate and isNull(endDate,cast('12/31/2200' as smalldatetime)) and product_id = @productID
```

I tried to 'cast' the '12/31/2200' to format it for a smalldatetime, but I'm getting the error:

"The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the date range for smalldatetime is 1900-01-01 through 2079-06-06 and your value is past the upper bound. The solution is to use a value inside the range, or another date type like datetime or datetime2.

`cast('12/31/2078' as smalldatetime)` would work for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the key:

```
and isNull(endDate,cast('2029-04-25T15:50:59.997' as smalldatetime))
```

You have to give the whole date even though it's a smalldatetime...  Also, you can't use 2200, it's too far in the future I guess...